# Solving a linear partial differential equation by separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am trying to solve

$$ A \cdot \frac {\partial^2 y} {\partial t^2} + B \cdot \frac {\partial^4 y} {\partial x^4} + C \cdot\frac {\partial^2 y} {\partial x^2} = q(x,t)$$

by separation of variables,

$$ y(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n(x) \cdot T_n(t)$$

with boundary conditions

$$ y(0,t) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(0,t) = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}(L,t) = \frac{\partial^3 y}{\partial x^3}(L,t) = 0$$

I haven't looked at differential equations for a long time. I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Separation of variables is possible if the linear PDE is homogeneous. This is not the case with the non-homogeneous term $q(x,t)$. It would be possible if this term was $q(x,t)y$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I haven't looked at differential equations for a long time. I really don't know where to start.

Comment: @JJacquelin What method would you recommend to solve the PDE?

Comment: It depends on what kind of function $q(x,t)$ is. In some cases one can guess a particular solution of the non-homogeneous PDE. If so, the PDE can be transformed into an homogeneous PDE and separation of variables becomes possible. An other way is the method of characteristics, not always analytically possible, depending on $q(x,t)$ and/or on boundary conditions. In practice, numerical methods of solving are recommended.

Comment: Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: @Dylan Yes, 0 =< x =< L $$ y(0,t) = 0 $$ $$ \frac {\partial y} {\partial x} (0,t) = 0 $$ $$ \frac {\partial^2 y} {\partial x^2} (L,t) = 0 $$ $$ \frac {\partial^3 y} {\partial x^3} (L,t) = 0 $$

Comment: Is that the only one? It would be helpful to include all the information in the question, since homogeneous boundary conditions may allow you to use separation of variables..

Comment: @Dylan I have edited it. I have 4 boundary conditions.

Comment: I meant add them *in the question*. I've done that for you.

Comment: If there are any more conditions, feel free to include them.

Comment: @Dylan I don't have anymore conditions but the differential equation might be wrong. I believe it's the differential equation for bending beam-columns with an added oscillatory term.

Comment: I'm thinking there should be some more conditions on the constants. But that's up to you to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the equation was homogeneous, then separation of variables would give

\begin{align} AT'' + \lambda T &= 0 \\ BX^{(4)} + CX'' - \lambda X &= 0 \end{align}

Now, the equation is not homogeneous, but we can still use the above results to decompose the solution into its eigenmodes.

Let $X_n(x)$ be solutions of the eigenvalue problem

$$ B{X_n}^{(4)} + C{X_n}'' - \lambda_n X_n = 0 $$ 
$$ X_n(0) = {X_n}'(0) = {X_n}''(L) = {X_n}'''(L) = 0 $$

The conditions in which these solutions exist depends on the constant $B,\ C$, which I won't go into here. If $X_n$ are mutually orthogonal and form a complete basis in $[0,L]$, then it's possible to write

\begin{align} u(x,t) &= \sum_n T_n(t)X_n(x) \\ q(x,t) &= \sum_n q_n(t)X_n(x) 
\end{align}

where $T_n(t)$ and $q_n(t)$ are time-dependent components of each respective function. Since $q$ is known, $q_n(t)$ can be found by applying the standard trick, i.e. multiplying through by $X_m(x)$ and integrating, which gives the result

$$ q_m(t) = \frac{\int_0^L q(x,t) X_m(t)\ dt }{\int_0^L {X_m}^2(x) \ dx} $$

Plugging the series form of $u(x,t)$ into the equation, we obtain (term-wise)

\begin{align} A{T_n}''X_n + T_n \big[ B{X_n}^{(4)} + C{X_n}''\big] &= q_n X_n \\
A{T_n}''X_n + T_n\big[\lambda_n X_n\big] &= q_n X_n
\end{align}

Therefore

$$ A{T_n}''(t) + \lambda_n T_n(t) = q_n(t) $$

It remains to solve this family of ODEs. If there's no specific form of $q(t)$, variation of parameters will do the job.

If you have any initial conditions, i.e. $u(x,0) = f(x),\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0) = g(x)$, they can also be employed here, once you decompose them to their corresponding series form.